# Centre of Circular Motion of $q$ in a Uniform Magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge

> **Initial Conditions**
>
> A charged particle $q$, is initially at rest at $(x,y)$. It is given velocity, $v_o~m.s^{-1}$ along positive $X$-axis.
>
> There exists a Uniform Magnetic Field $B_0$ in the whole region along positive $Z$-axis.

After the particle in given the velocity, we know that it experiences some force, due to the presence of Magnetic Field, in a direction perpendicular to both $B$ & $v$. This causes the charged particle to move in a cirle of radius, $r = \frac{m.v}{q.B}$

**So, how do we find the centre of this circular motion ?**

Comment: Just using the right hand rule and that charge comes in two polarities you can show there are two circles that can be made by the particle.

Comment: I meant to ask about only for one type of charge [either positive or negative], so I have edited the question to be specific about positive charge now

Comment: The center depends on the initial conditions. The initial position and velocity will be on a tangent to the circle.

Comment: If the charge and magnetic field are constant you can also get an infinite number of circular paths from the velocity alone

Comment: If started from origin with, let us say, v = i + j m/s then there will be one circle or more than one, this is what I wanted to know

Comment: @Triatticus yes I know that, by changing magnitude of velocity, we can get different circles as radius changes, but I meant to ask with all conditions fixed, where will be the centre with respect to initial position ?

Comment: How is it possible to start from rest with a velocity that is non-zero?

Comment: @BillN Initial state is rest position at origin, then it is given a velocity. But why is that even a concern ?

Comment: @Goarkz What's the acceleration? How long does it accelerate? That changes the point about which it will circulate. Basically, you haven't given enough detail about how the initial condition of the particle.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I just meant, charged particle is imparted some velocity due to some sudden impulse, and I am stating that it starts with that velocity from Origin and only force due to Magnetic field is acting on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a right handed system with, B, in the, +z , direction, and, v, at the origin, and going in the, +x, direction, a positive charge will be deflected toward the, -y, direction.  The center of the circle will be on the y axis at: y = -r.

Comment: So, you mean that (0,-r) will be center but why? why not (0,0) ? could you please give more details on it

Comment: (0,0) is one of the points _on_ the circle, (the charge starts there) so it can't be the center.